# How to maintain position of each view when rotating device?

Tags: ios

Normally, when we orient from portrait to landscape, the entire view rotates and "stretches" to adjust the changed screen size, and updating the subviews to match.

What I want to achieve is to NOT rotate the entire view, but rather rotate each individual element in place, e.g maintaining their actual location on the screen.

This can be seen in the stock "Camera" app, e.g where the "Flip camera"-button always is on the exact same location on the screen, but orienting correctly, instead of the entire screen rotating.

If I flip the phone from landscape left to landscape right, I don't want the entire screen to flip 180 degrees, but each element individually stay in place and rotate.

I want to make something like this:

Portrait
[image: Portrait]

Landscape turned clockwise (Img1/Text1 would be first if oriented counter-clockwise, and the images would be below the texts).
[image: Landscape]

Is this possible to do in any other way than disabling rotation for the entire app and then manually rotate each element based on orientation?
I feel that manual rotation like this would require a lot of work, especially with text, with how to decide how much width a label gets etc.

Any smart solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use nested `UIStackView`s with `Adaptive Layout` to develop such kind User Interface.

There is no code as I developed this completely in the `storyboard` itself.

Storyboard File:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ftsrfPkdtA0F0wuWEjkcCJYjI3DSPSRO/view?usp=sharing

In Portrait:

[image]

In Landscape:

[image]

Source for the Storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14109" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="vhg-TG-ZL3">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="landscape">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
        <capability name="Aspect ratio constraints" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="Stack View standard spacing" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller2-->
        <scene sceneID="awc-c5-ATF">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="vhg-TG-ZL3" customClass="ViewController2" customModule="SW4Temp" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="hTC-e3-Ut5">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="667" height="375"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" spacingType="standard" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Gtq-Mi-7ud">
                                <rect key="frame" x="16" y="16" width="635" height="108.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alignment="center" spacingType="standard" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="k1S-mL-qYO">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="206.5" height="108.5"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Qgz-HE-riz">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="63" y="0.0" width="80" height="80"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.94117647059999998" green="0.58823529409999997" blue="0.29411764709999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="80" id="daX-ya-3IJ"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Qgz-HE-riz" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="erh-Sa-Mm0"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 1" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pfd-Cb-Ywa">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="76.5" y="88" width="53.5" height="20.5"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <variation key="heightClass=compact-widthClass=compact" axis="vertical"/>
                                        <variation key="heightClass=compact-widthClass=regular" axis="vertical"/>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alignment="center" spacingType="standard" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="s9a-dA-1Bb">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="214.5" y="0.0" width="206" height="108.5"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Dau-Qz-ghH">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="63" y="0.0" width="80" height="80"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.14913141730000001" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Dau-Qz-ghH" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="7eH-AY-pzT"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="80" id="vd7-nt-yn4"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 2" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4qd-bl-v4g">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="75" y="88" width="56" height="20.5"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <variation key="heightClass=compact-widthClass=compact" axis="vertical"/>
                                        <variation key="heightClass=compact-widthClass=regular" axis="vertical"/>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alignment="center" spacingType="standard" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="i46-aO-FbE">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="428.5" y="0.0" width="206.5" height="108.5"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="5Us-ZC-UrI">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="63.5" y="0.0" width="80" height="80"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="1" blue="0.0" alpha="0.84999999999999998" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="80" id="SBb-j3-6dT"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="5Us-ZC-UrI" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="bMn-hy-xGO"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="top" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 3" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6s1-yZ-SE5">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="75" y="88" width="56.5" height="20.5"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <variation key="heightClass=compact-widthClass=compact" axis="vertical"/>
                                        <variation key="heightClass=compact-widthClass=regular" axis="vertical"/>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <variation key="heightClass=compact-widthClass=compact" axis="horizontal"/>
                                <variation key="heightClass=compact-widthClass=regular" axis="horizontal"/>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="cw1-6J-jUF" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Gtq-Mi-7ud" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="21L-TP-1k5"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Gtq-Mi-7ud" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="cw1-6J-jUF" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="BC4-ZA-yHF"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Gtq-Mi-7ud" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="hTC-e3-Ut5" secondAttribute="top" id="T00-yG-pwX">
                                <variation key="heightClass=compact-widthClass=compact" constant="16"/>
                                <variation key="heightClass=compact-widthClass=regular" constant="16"/>
                            </constraint>
                            <constraint firstItem="cw1-6J-jUF" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Gtq-Mi-7ud" secondAttribute="bottom" id="j8A-YW-4fG"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="cw1-6J-jUF"/>
                        <variation key="heightClass=compact-widthClass=compact">
                            <mask key="constraints">
                                <exclude reference="j8A-YW-4fG"/>
                            </mask>
                        </variation>
                        <variation key="heightClass=compact-widthClass=regular">
                            <mask key="constraints">
                                <exclude reference="j8A-YW-4fG"/>
                            </mask>
                        </variation>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Yq1-y6-rRF" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-1458.4000000000001" y="45.42728635682159"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: While your answer solves the issue, it's best not to simply post links to files - links can die. I've added your storyboard source code to your answer, but you should also ***describe*** what you did. See [answer]

Comment: Thank you @DonMag, thought to do so but I didn't.